# build.gradle repository merge

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have projects that depend on the same core library. I need to include a custom repository for a library i am using. I want to include the custom repository in one place for all the projects. So in the Library's build.grade i added

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

        maven {
            url "http://dl.bintray.com/urbanairship/android"
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

When i try to build my project it complains about not being able to find the library. If take the above code and place it in the projects build.gradle instead it complies. How can I get the libraries repositories found when i compile the projects without including it in each projects build.gradle?

Comment: Have you configured `settings.gradle` file as well?

Comment: What do you mean by configured? i have include ':library'
project(':library').projectDir = new File('../../../library')

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `allprojects` closure use the `subprojects` closure.  Swapping out the closure name should fix your problem.

example:

```
subprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

        maven {
            url "http://dl.bintray.com/urbanairship/android"
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```